# My Google Chrome slowness at first run

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser

I use latest version of Google Chrome browser on my Windows 7 machine. The problem is that, chrome is very slow at first run, It takes more than 20 seconds to finally loads the page (any page, say Google.com).

Please consider these cases:

1- Only my Google chrome is this way. My IE 11 and Mozilla Firefox are fine and very faster in first run.
2- I have uninstalled and re-installed times the chrome by default uninstallation method and also by *Revo Uninstaller Pro* in advanced mode but no change occurred!
3- I have the same version of chrome on my Windows 8.1 (which is on virtual machine installed on Windows 7). It has no bug and is fine at first run and also later.

These cases imply that the problem has to do with my Windows 7 OS.
What ideas do you have for getting rid of that problem with Chrome please?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear your browser cookies,bookmarks,cache & also check your internet speed and malware test.

otherwise going to **Wrench>Settings>Show Advanced Settings and unchecking**  `'Enable phishing and malware protection'`   Everything works fine now!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But please look, when chrome is just installed and previous cookies, history, bookmarks are already deleted when uninstalling process, so why this new should show the slowness again? And as I said IE is fine (so no Internet speed is cause)! +1 vote for your attempt to help me :) And I don't like security risks my friend!

Comment: @user3724662 try that one it some times help to reset winsock,open your admin command prompt and type "netsh" and then press enter,after type  "winsock reset" press enter.i hope it will solve your problem

Comment: I too tested it. While IE 11 takes 3 seconds to load the yahoo.com at first run, chrome takes about 15 seconds to load google.com :(

Comment: compare seconds to load normal and incognito mode...

Comment: In incognito I should refresh the page (F5) several times to get the chrome loading page. Apparently delay in this state is more.

Comment: @user3724662 there is a lot of reasons that may slow at first run,try also these two,first one Go to advanced settings in settings and in network selection click "change proxy settings",it will open in properties dialog box click "LAN settings" and  Deselect the "Automatically detect settings" check box. after restart your browser and start...second one is go to ‘Settings’. Open ‘Show Advanced Settings’ at the bottom of the page. Go almost to the bottom of this page to the ’System’ section and un check the box and turn off "Use Hardware Acceleration When Available”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17499/discussion-between-new-guy-and-user3724662).

Comment: @user3724662 In my Google Chrome for Mac, the settings is actually called “Predict network actions to improve page load performance“. Therefore, just untick.its also grow up your speed...

Comment: I sent a message with the @nEwgUy sign in chat environment. I don't know did you see it or no.